# How to compile Quake 2 source with

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile the [official full Quake2 source code](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-2) using `MSVC 2019` on Windows 10.

When I open `quake2.dsw` in my `MSVC 2019`, it tries to migrate the workspace to work with the current version of the IDE, but it fails. For each project in the solution, I'm getting this error in the Migration Report:

> Unable to convert project. Please make sure this is a valid Visual C++ 6.0 project

How to get `MSVC 2019` to compile the code?

Comment: You may want to investigate some of the 526 forks for updated builds. I found one that has CMake support which may be a better option than trying to convert the Visual C++ 6.0 dsw file to use for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @drescherjm I've tried the version You've proposed but still having the same errors!:-(

Comment: You should not use the .dsw file from that version or any other fork. You need to use the `CMakeLists.txt` instead and not try to convert the project.

Comment: @drescherjm So NOT to use the default automatic migration BUT rather do it manually?

Comment: Neither option. The `CMakeLists.txt` could be used to generate a project file for Visual Studio directly. Modern versions of VS support this file. If that does not work I assume one of the other forks has a newer project file that is compatible.