# Can't compile the official Quake 2 source code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've downloaded the official Quake 2 source code but can't compile it with any of `MSVC` I have access to.

I've tried to just open the workspace (*quake2.dsw*) in the old `Visual C++ 6.0` (Enterprise Edition) as the official *readme.txt* states:

> This is the complete source code for Quake 2, version 3.19, buildable
> with visual C++ 6.0

But just NOTHING happens - no errors, no any info no files loaded!

When I try to open the workspace in `MSVC 2008, 2017 or 2019` the migration fails for all the 5 projects inside the workspace/solution.

The most disturbing why cant I open the solution just in `MSVC 6.0` since it was indeed created using this exact version?!

Comment: 20 years  and six major OS versions later, I'm not certain that MSVS 6 will even run properly. What happens if you spin up a Windows XP Virtual machine, install MSVC in it, and then build?

Comment: did you try cmake as suggested last time you asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573279/how-to-compile-quake-2-source-with